# Waypoints y Animaciones en HTML con JQuery y CSS

Tags: html, jquery, css, html5, css3

Buen día, estoy intentando implementar animaciones a elementos cuando se muestren en pantalla, pero no logro hacerlo, creo que el problema esta en el codigo JQuery que me encuentro usando, ya que al intentar añadir una clase al objeto no lo hace, pero si ejecuto cualquier otra cosa por ejemplo un `alert` lo muestra, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
$('.darAnim').waypoint(
    function(direction)
    {
      alert($(this).attr('id'));
      $(this).toggleClass('main');
      },
      {offset: '70%',triggerOnce: true
    });
});
```

Este es el código completo

```html
<style>.darAnim{/*opacity:0;*/}.main {font-size: 120%;color: red;</style>

<h1 id="n1" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n2" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n3" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n4" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n5" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n6" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n7" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n8" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n9" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn1" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn2" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn3" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn4" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn5" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn6" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn7" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints/blob/master/lib/jquery.waypoints.js'></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.darAnim').waypoint(
    function(direction) {
      $(this).toggleClass('main');
    }, {
      offset: '70%',
      triggerOnce: true
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Qué versión de Waypoint y jQuery estás usando?

Comment: Qué es lo que querés que haga tu función? Ya sé que es lo que está fallando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo utilizo la librería waypoints en combinación con la librería animate.css en el elemento que quieras realizar la animación pon la clase css animated y fadeInUp (Hay muchas más puedes buscar en la pagina de animate.css)
Suerte.

```js
$('.animated').waypoint(function () {
    $(this).addClass('animated-active');
}, {offset: '100%',
    triggerOnce: true});
```

```css
.circle{
height:100px;
width:100px;
background-color:blue;
border-radius:50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/noframework.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="circle animated fadeInUp"></div>
<div class="circle animated fadeInLeft"></div>
```

Comment: Lo intente probar pero me salio un error que dice:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).waypoint is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous>

Answer (score 1):

Está fallando porque al incluir la librería de waypoint estás pegando la URL de github con la vista y no al archivo javascript. Te recomiendo en esos casos usar CDNs, este es el de waypoint:      `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js` y porque estás pasando dentro de la función de `.ready(function($))` el signo `$` entonces sobre escribe el jQuery.
Lo otro es que el `$(this)` está tomando como dentro de la función y no del elemento `darAnim`, entonces deberías agregarlo a una variable y luego llamarlo.

Debería quedar:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var darAnim = $('.darAnim');
  darAnim.waypoint(
    function(direction) {
      alert(darAnim.attr('id'));
      darAnim.toggleClass('main');
    }, {
      offset: '70%',
      triggerOnce: true
    });
});
```

```css
.darAnim{
  /*opacity:0;*/
}
.main {
  font-size: 120%;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="n1" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n2" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n3" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n4" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n5" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n6" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n7" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n8" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="n9" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn1" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn2" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn3" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn4" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn5" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn6" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>
<h1 id="nn7" class="darAnim" style="margin-bottom: 300px;">Example</h1>

<script type='text/javascript' src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: 1. SI esta incluida la librería

Comment: 2. No entiendo lo que quieres decir

Comment: @josemarquez podés usar la variable `jQuery` o `$`, eso no debería traer problemas, lo que no entiendo es porqué hiciste lo siguiente `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {`, ese `$` dentro del `function` es probable que sea el causante del error.

Comment: Entonces lo quito?

Comment: Lo puse así por que lo vi en un tutorial

Comment: Probá si con el fragmente que te pasé funciona y decime o intenta de editar tu pregunta y poner algo más verificable para probar.

Comment: Acabo de compartir el codigo completo, el script del waypoint no se si funcione insertandola así, yo la tengo descargada

Comment: Lo unico que falla es el $(this) por que si le pongo $('#n9') por ejemplo, lo realiza como debería

Comment: Dime si te funcionó con la modificación que le di.

Comment: Sigue sin agregar la clase al elemento